# What is "auxiliary information" in context of cryptographic accumulators?

Tags: rsa, terminology, accumulators

I have been reading a paper about accumulators (title of the paper: ["Universal Accumulators with Efficient Nonmembership Proofs"](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ninghui/papers/accumulator_acns07.pdf)). It mentions "auxiliary information" about a function, which I couldn't quite understand. Can anyone explain the term in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will vary from construction to construction, but for the purposes of the scheme outlined in the paper where the function is
$$f_N(g,x):=g^x\pmod N$$
(or similar) the auxiliary information is the prime factorisation of $N$ (see the second bullet of Construction 1) or equivalently the value of the Euler $\phi$-function of $N$  (see the first bullet of Construction 2).